# Modular Arithmetic Substitution Problem in Multiplication

Tags: modular-arithmetic

9<sup>9</sup> ≡ 387,420,489 ≡ 5 (mod 22)

However I have tried to reach this result using the following steps and I got it wrong:

9<sup>9</sup> ≡ 9<sup>3</sup> x 9<sup>3</sup> x 9<sup>3</sup> ≡ 729 x 729 x 729 ≡ 3 x 3 x 3 ≡ 18 (mod 22)

I can use this substitution in sum operations, but is it correct to say that I cannot do the same for multiplications?

Comment: $3^3$ is not $\equiv 18(22)$ dear

Comment: and that's obviously the problem! the problem was way more stupid than I assessed. 3 x 3 x 3 ain't 18, but 27. Thanks @ShamimAkhtar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$3^3 = 27 \equiv 5 \,(\text{mod}\,\,22)$

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to go about it:
$$\varphi(22)=10;1\equiv 9^{10}=9\cdot9^9 \pmod {22}\\5\cdot 9=45=22\cdot2+1\equiv 1 \pmod {22}$$ This uses Euler's totient theorem. most substitutions are still valid in modular arithmetic. as it's an extension of normal arithmetic.

Comment: This notation that you used is much clearer, I will keep it in mind and use it going forth. Many thanks!